# Autostart when windows reboots

Tags: c#, windows, startup, autostart

I'm trying to write a simple program in C sharp that should Autostart when Windows boots and keep working. I have tried several methods, which did not work though. Any suggestions? Note: I'm a beginner.

I tried:

```
var thisPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                    RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
                    string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
                    string name = Path.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath);
                    if (regKey == null) // Key not existing, we need to create the key.
                    {
                       Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");

                    }

                    regKey.SetValue(name, (string)path, RegistryValueKind.String);
```

and also:

```
string startupFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
            WshShell shell = new WshShell();
            string shortcutAddress = startupFolder + @"\Mylibraryxd.lnk";
            IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
            shortcut.Description = "A startup shortcut. If you delete this shortcut from your computer, LaunchOnStartup.exe will not launch on Windows Startup"; // set the description of the shortcut
            shortcut.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath; /* working directory */
            shortcut.TargetPath = Application.ExecutablePath; /* path of the executable */
            shortcut.Save(); // save the shortcut
```

None of these worked properly, do you have any ideas? Thank you!!!

Comment: Was your process running with administrative privileges?

Comment: To be clear - are you wanting the program to start when windows has started up, even if no user has logged in? Or are you wanting to launch the program as (each) user logs on?

Comment: Execute msconfig from your run prompt to see if your application is in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can press `Windows + R` and write `shell:startup`. if you have the file you can drag and drop it there or just create a link. Everything in that folder automaticly starts as soon as the user is logged in. That means you don't have to link it in the code itself.